# How do I get the programming languages of the user from the GitHub Api?

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to get the **programming languages** of a GitHub user from the **GitHub Api**. I haven't found an endpoint for this in the documentation. How can I do this?

**Expected result**

```
PHP 33%,
Dockerfile 16%,
JavaScript 20%,
etc.
```

#### Important Note to my question

The question should actually be: Does an endpoint exist for this?  Because if not, I have to solve it programmatically. Then I would probably know how to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some more research. GitHub does **not** offer an endpoint for this particular case. Therefore, the solution is to solve it programmatically.

**Here are the steps how to do it:**

`https://api.github.com/users/JohnDoe/repos` returns a json with all repositories of the user (JohnDoe). Iterate these objects and collect the `language`. The rest is just simple percentage calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I pull the languages from multiple repos.

I used javascript/jquery, the octokit package

Documenation here: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18

I pulled all repos and put them into a const so I could pull any data from any repository I was the direct owner of:

```js
const repositories = await octokit.request('GET /user/repos?page=1&per_page=1000', { type: 'owner' });
```

Then pulled languages from specific repo and assigned it to const languages

```js
// returns languages of specific repository in bytes - 1 byte is enough to hold about 1 typed character, e.g. 'b' or 'X' or '$'
const languages = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/languages', { owner: 'jpatterson933', repo: "resume" });
```

and it returns this as the response when you console.log(res):

```js
console.log(languages)
```

//returns this in the console

{HTML: 6869, CSS: 5123, JavaScript: 2958}

So from here, you can add the total bytes of each language together and get a total which you can then use to create "percentages of languages I have ever used on Github" or use the individual stats to make cool graphs of languages used in individual repositories and show something like "percentages of each language used in x repo"